# qq ajax file uploader - submit values with onSubmit

Tags: ajax, variables, submit, uploader, fine-uploader

Does anybody know how to submit element values along with submitted uploaded AJAX file using qq AJAX file uploader? (http://valums.com/ajax-upload/).

Options only support static binding, but I need to collect values just before submission of the file.

For example, I have a checkbox id=ofield-delete-previous-pdf and I want to submit whether it is checked or not. Checkbox can be un/checked after qq javascript is loaded.

Following code does not work for me:

```
'onSubmit'=>'function(file, ext){
    var delete=$("#ofield-delete-previous-pdf").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
    qq.FileUploaderBasic.prototype.setParams({ **<-- not working**
        "paramDeletePrevious":delete
    });
}'
```

How can I attach variable "delete" to qq object?

Thank you in advance.
Lubos

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader#instance-methods), following should work:

```
onSubmit : function(id, fileName){
    var delete=$("#check-delete-previous").is(":checked");
    this.setParams({ 
        "deletePrevious" : delete,
        "otherValue" : $("#some-element").val(),
    });
},
```

In fact, following worked only for me:

```
onSubmit : function(id, fileName){
    var delete=$("#check-delete-previous").is(":checked");
    this.params.deletePrevious = delete;
},
```

EDIT: After I updated to latest version, first example works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Fine Uploader you are using, but in the last couple versions at least (including the current version - 3.0), the setParams function is the correct (and only) way to do this.  Your second block of code is not valid.